# Cookie JSessionID not present in Javascript HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

i've a jsp page in which i would make a HTTP POST to my servlet.
My web-app manage a session.
When i click to the below button:

```
<button onclick="SendSDPLine()"> </button>
```

This is what is executed:

```
  <script  type= text/javascript>

  function SendSDPLine(){

                var sdp="12345";
                var url = "http://localhost:8080/AccountController";
                var action_type = "InsertSDPLine"

                $.ajax({
                      type:    "POST",
                      url:     url,
                      data:{
                          "action"  : action_type,
                          "sdpline" : sdp


                      },
                      success: function(data) {

                        alert('sdp inviato!');

                     },
                      // vvv---- This is the new bit
                      error:   function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log("Error, status = " + textStatus + ", " +
                                  "error thrown: " + errorThrown
                            );
                      }
                    });

  }
```

Well, i see 404 to `localhost:8080/AccountController/`

But, when i point to this servlet via a JSP POST, for example inside a form:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="AccountController?action=InsertSDPLine">

    <span style="color:red"> ${message}</span>

     <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" required="required" name="username"/>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="button-container">

    <button><span>Send</span></button> 
  </div>

</form>
```

there is 200 ok. Checking console's network tab, i see that in the JSP POST request there is the session cookie (JSessionID), but not in the JS HTTP POST.
Why this change of behaviour?

Comment: localhost:8080 might be interpreted as cross origin. Have you tried adding the `withCredentials` header to the request?

Comment: @Shilly yes, but no change. My jsp page is hosted on localhost:8080.

Comment: Your form's `action` is specified as a relative path from where the form itself is being served--what is the browser URL when the form is loaded? What happens if you change the `action` to be a fully-qualified URL like "http://localhost:8080/AccountController?action=insertSDPLine"? It's possible your servlet has a context other than `/`, in which case the URL would need to specify that context. Also, your form behavior is different from your function--the function includes `action` and `sdpline` params in the POST body; your form includes at least the `action` parameter as a URL parameter.

Comment: @Palpatim the jsp page in which there is the form is http://localhost/Shine4/UtenteWebRTC.jsp . I've tried action="localhost:8080/AccountController?action=insertSDPLine" but i have 500 error.

Comment: If that's the case, then your servlet is listening on `http://localhost/Shine4/AccountController`. Don't forget that your `action` in the form needs to include a scheme if you're going to specify the host. Either use the existing scheme (`//localhost:8080/...`) or specify it (`http://localhost:8080/...`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Palpatim. So, what could i modify? And how? I'd like using Javascript POST, instead a form JSP POST..

Comment: Change the URL in your `SendSDPline` function to properly reflect the servlet URL.

Comment: Thanks @Palpatim, it works with URL http://localhost:8080/Shine4/AccountController !